# How to print out elements from the list that have the difference of 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, element

Let's say we have a list with integers only:

```
list = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]
```

Now, I want to print out of that list all element pairs that have the difference of 2. So I want my program to print out next:

```
12, 14

22, 24

29, 31

77, 79
```

I tried a lot of things but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: don’t use built-ins as names for your data structures!!

Comment: What if there will be `[1, 34, 32, 9, 12, 14]`. As you can see there is a -ve difference `-2` (34, 32), +ve difference `2` (12, 14). You want to retain both or just +ve one?

Comment: Please share the most promising code you have tried. I bet the stackoverflow community will help you finish that code.

Comment: Is the list guaranteed to be sorted? Will they always be sequential in the list? These constraints affect the best approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]

result = [(x, y) for x, y in combinations(lst, r=2) if abs(x - y) == 2]

for first, second in result:
    print(first, second)
```

**Output**

```
12 14
22 24
29 31
77 79
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple list comprehensions can solve this:

```
l = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]
l1 = [(x1,x2) for x1 in l for x2 in l if (x1-x2 == 2)]
print(l1)
# [(14, 12), (24, 22), (31, 29), (79, 77)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code meets your requirement.

```
list1 = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]

for x in list1:
    if x+2 in list1:
        print(x,", ",x+2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list is sorted and has no repeating elements the difference of 2 can be found only in the groups of three sequential elements:

```
l = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]

l = sorted(set(l)) # if l is not sorted and has repeating elements

for a, b, c in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]):
    if b - a == 2:
        print(a, b)
    elif c - a == 2:
        print(a, c)
# 12 14
# 22 24
# 29 31
# 77 79
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to iterate straight through the loop, try using an *integer* to loop through it instead, using `range(len(my_list))`:

```
my_list = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
    if my_list[i+1] - my_list[i] == 2:
        print("%d, %d" % (my_list[i], my_list[i+1]))
```

Output:

```
12, 14
22, 24
29, 31
77, 79
```

Comment: It doesn’t work with [1, 2, 3, 4]. The result must be 1, 3 and 2, 4.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations as c
mlst = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]
print ([(i,j) for i,j in c(mlst,2) if abs(i-j) == 2])

# output: [(12, 14), (22, 24), (29, 31), (77, 79)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define e method that returns consecutive pairs based on condition:

```
def each_cons(predicate, iterable):
  i, size = 0, len(iterable)
  while i < size-2:
    if predicate(iterable[i], iterable[i+1]):
      yield iterable[i:i+2]
    i += 1
```

Then just call it setting the condition:

```
array = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]

each_cons(lambda x, y: y - x == 2, array)
#=>  [[12, 14], [22, 24], [29, 31], [77, 79]]
```

Comment: It doesn’t function for this list: [1, 2, 3, 4]. The result must be [[1, 3], [2, 4]]

Answer (score 0):

`@bobojmaj`, you can also try like this.

```
>>> 
>>> l = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]
>>> output = [(l[i], l[j]) for i in range(len(l) - 1) for j in range(i + 1, len(l)) if abs(l[i] - l[j]) == 2]
>>> output
[(12, 14), (22, 24), (29, 31), (77, 79)]
>>> 
>>> s = '\n'.join([str(output[i][0]) + ', ' + str(output[i][1]) for i in range(len(output))])
>>> print(s)
12, 14
22, 24
29, 31
77, 79
>>>
```

And if your elements are in a group of 2 as in your example then the following.

```
>>> 
>>> l = [1, 7, 12, 14, 22, 24, 29, 31, 39, 45, 77, 79, 85, 100]
>>> 
>>> n = len(l) - 1
>>> output = [(l[i], l[i + 1]) for i in range(0, n, 2) if abs(l[i] - l[i + 1]) == 2]
>>> output
[(12, 14), (22, 24), (29, 31), (77, 79)]
>>>
```